# How does C# manage uninitialized classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using C# in Unity and I need to know how does C# manages classes in order to know if I need to set all of the values during or after the `new` to avoid invalid reads or if I can leave them as they are.

With this example I get the following output :

```
class Test {
  public int test;
}
Test buffer = new Test;
Debug.Log(buffer.test);
```

> 0
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Does this mean the variable types all have a default value or should I be more careful when instantiating a Class ?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I did, but for this project I needed to be sure I was not getting lucky or had a configuration I was not aware of and needed to confirm it.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#instance-variables-in-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .Net framework initializes all fields to their default values (`0` or `null`).

Comment: Does it set other classes within the class to Null too ?

Comment: It sets objects to null and primitives to their default value. (bool = false, numerical value types(int, float...) = 0).